# Dell OMSA HTTPS errors

Tags: security, https, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

On a non-virtualized server running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter with application Dell OpenManage Systems Management Software (64-Bit) version 7.4.0 installed, opening Dell OpenManage Server Administrator (`https://<hostname>:1311`):

- Using Internet Explorer version 11.0.9600.18450 (latest) fails with error:

  > This page can’t be displayed
- Using Google Chrome version 46.0.2490.71 (portable) fails with error:

  > Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key
  >
  > ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY
  >
  > This error can occur when connecting to a secure (HTTPS) server. It means that the server is trying to set up a secure connection but, due to a disastrous misconfiguration, the connection wouldn't be secure at all!
  >
  > In this case the server needs to be fixed. Google Chrome won't use insecure connections in order to protect your privacy.
- Using Google Chrome version 53.0.2785.143 (latest) succeeds but reports:

  > This site uses a weak security configuration (SHA-1 signatures), so your connection may not be private.

Comment: This is caused by out-dated SSL certificate. Have you tried upgrading to a newer version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as Dell doesn't provide OMSA updates that use newer SSL/TLS versions there isn't much you can do about it than using an older browser that still supports the old ciphers.

For the few older machines I have running I keep an older version of Firefox around. If you download a portable edition you can place it on an USB thumb drive or someplace else where it doesn't hurt or interfere. If you only use it for these management task you are fairly safe. If you are really paranoid, you can run it in a sandbox.

Browser versions that should be working (not fully tested):

- Chrome 40
- Firefox 38